# How do I make Stem install from a specific git branch with Poetry?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am trying to install the Python library [Stem](https://github.com/torproject/stem) as a dependency of another Python app that uses Poetry, [OnionShare](https://github.com/onionshare/onionshare).

Specifically I am trying to install a specific branch of the Stem git repository, 'maint'.

I run this command and get the subsequent error:

```
poetry add git+https://github.com/torproject/stem.git#maint


[RuntimeError]
Unable to retrieve the package version for /tmp/pypoetry-git-stem9gmhpzio
```

This looks like this issue described [here](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2176) - whereby, Poetry can't parse the 'version' from the project's `setup.py` because it isn't a simple string, it's something that needs to be enumerated in a way that Poetry won't do.

So I tried forking the repo, and changed the 'name' and the 'version' in `setup.py` to be simple strings, and I still got the same error.

The Stem developer [isn't interested in making it work with Poetry](https://github.com/torproject/stem/pull/98) (or really anything to do with Stem, anymore)

What needs to change in Stem's `setup.py` to make it work with Poetry?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of poetry do you use? No problem for me here.

Comment: @finswimmer I am using Poetry 1.0.5 on Debian 10 (Python 3.7 in use). I think I pip installed it, I see it's a very old version. Maybe a newer version's fixed it! What version did you use?

Comment: You have to use poetry >1.1.0. There we implement to a way to get dynamic version numbers. Current stable release is 1.1.8. This is what I use.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to [get it to work](https://github.com/onionshare/stem/commit/18e3032ef3b69441862a018daff02394607e041a) in the end. It was a combination of:

1. hardcode the version string (as per the above link to the Poetry upstream issue)
2. Use `from distutils.core import setup` and then `setup()` rather than call `distutils.core.setup()` directly
3. Don't use a try/finally statement

Only after all three of these were changed, was Poetry happy with Stem's setup.py. I'm still not sure why, but at least it works now.